# Why did not the changes affect real time when I make changes in codes

Tags: javascript, css, caching

I'm developing website for a real estate agency. I keep on making changes in my code like jQuery , css etc...
But I can't see the changes real time. It show the previous cached things.

For example : 
If I change the logo also I need to directly call the url to work. It working on Private window of the browser.

I need to get real time changes

Answer (score 0):

For prevent caching while development, you can use `shift+f5` (or `control+shift+r`) in chrome (it will reload ignoring cashe). also you can check `disable cache` in chrome dev tools in network tab. (it will disable cache only when dev tools are open.).

also you can use `live-server` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)) to reload page when you save your doc (live preview). there are some online code editors that support live preview as well (like [playcode](https://playcode.io/online-javascript-editor))

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways.

1 - ) Disable cache from google chrome.
[image: Google Chrome]

2 - ) You can add "? v" at the end of the file path.
[image: ?V=1]

You should change the number in the middle every time you want to see the new version.

If you say I don't want to change without stopping.

I don't know which infrastructure it uses.

I was using "

```
<link href='css/basic.css?v=@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

" in mvc.